# WordPress Front end Form - Enable to Submit PHP Codes

Tags: security, front-end, publish

I just create a front end form to submit posts for public persons.

It works fine.

I need to allow to submit PHP codes (because it is PHP tutorial site) via that form. I need to make sure it not damage my site.

How to make it secure?

Answer (score 0):

Running forms through `the_content` filter should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what type of codes should I run  through the_content filter.

Comment: All of your form input values.